# Dynamically change on size on Ionic But its changing the Theme As well

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to change the Font size of the ionic App but its in need changing the Color (theme) of the Entire application..

For better understanding the problem, please refer to the following link video:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1iifRarhNu8uGBUU8kkSe5T17RyBDG4N8

Fonts HTMl File

```
    <ion-content padding>
      <ion-label></ion-label>
      <ion-item>
          <ion-label  >Font Size</ion-label>
          <ion-select [(ngModel)]="Font">
            <ion-option value="L">Large</ion-option>
            <ion-option value="S">Small</ion-option>

          </ion-select>
        </ion-item>
        <button ion-button full (click)="toggleAppTheme1()">Apply</button>
```

the FOONT.TS file looks like

```
      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public settings: SettingsProvider) 
      {
        this.settings.getActiveFont().subscribe(val => this.selectedFont = val);

      }

      toggleAppTheme1()
      { 
        debugger;
        if (this.Font=='L'){ this.settings.setActiveFont('Large-Font');}

        if(this.Font=='S'){ this.settings.setActiveFont('Small-Font');}
```

the provider setting.ts contains like

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/Rx';

    @Injectable()
    export class SettingsProvider {

    private theme: BehaviorSubject<String>;

    private font: BehaviorSubject<String>;

      constructor() {
    this.theme= new BehaviorSubject('Dark-theme');
    //this.font = new BehaviorSubject('Large-Font');

    this.font= new BehaviorSubject('Small-Font');

    // this.theme= new BehaviorSubject('Small-Font');
        console.log('Hello SettingsProvider Provider');
      }

      setActiveTheme(val){

      debugger
        this.theme.next(val);
      }

      getActiveTheme(){

      return this.theme.asObservable();
      }

      setActiveFont(val)
      {
        debugger;
        //this.theme.next(val);
        this.font.next(val);
      }
      getActiveFont(){
        //return this.theme.asObservable();
        return this.font.asObservable();
      }

    }
```

i have Created Themes . scss to change Dynamically changing the Look and Feel ,
large.scss

```
.Large-Font{
ion-content{
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

}

Small.scss

```
.Large-Font{
ion-content{
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

}

Dark.theme.scss

```
.Dark-theme{
ion-content{
    background-color: #090f2f;
    color: #fff;
}
.card-header {
    //color: #000000;
    color: #fff;
}
.card {
     background-color: #090f2f; // black
    //background-color: #ffffff; // black
    box-shadow: none;

  }

.toolbar-title{
     color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
   // color:rgb(24, 23, 23);
}
.header .toolbar-background{
  border-color: #ff0fff;
// border-color: #305f38fd;
    background-color: #090f2f;
}
.footer .toolbar-background{
    border-color: #ff15ff;
    background-color: #090f2f;
}
```

}

light theme.scss

```
.light-theme{
ion-content{
    background-color: #ffff;
}

.login {
    background: #ffff;
        }

 .card-header-ios {
            color: ffff;
    }

.toolbar-background{
        background-color: #ffff;
}

.card {
    background-color: #e5e7ee; // black
    box-shadow: none;

  }
```

}

medium.scss

```
                .Medium-theme{
                ion-content{
                    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
                    // color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
                }

                .login {
                    //background: rgba(248, 248, 248, 0.795);
                    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
                        }

                .card-header-ios {
                            color: ffff;
                    }

                .toolbar-background{
                        background-color: #014f52;
                }

                .card {
                    background-color: #fafafa; // black
                    box-shadow: none;

                }

            }
```

in the app.comopent .ts

```
 this.initializeApp();



this.settings.getActiveFont().subscribe(val => this.selectedFont = val);

this.settings.getActiveTheme().subscribe(val => this.selectedTheme = val);
// used for an example of ngFor and navigation
```

in the APP.html

```
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false" [class]="selectedFont" [class]="selectedTheme"></ion-nav>
```

for the theme.html

```
   <ion-label>Dark/Light</ion-label>
   <ion-item>
       <ion-label  >Color </ion-label>
       <ion-select [(ngModel)]="Color ">
         <!-- <ion-option selected disabled value="D">Dark</ion-option> -->
         <ion-option disabled="disabled" value="D">Dark</ion-option>
         <ion-option value="L">light</ion-option>
         <ion-option value="p">Pale</ion-option>

         <!-- <ion-option value="M">medium</ion-option> -->

         <!-- <ion-option value="R">Rich</ion-option> -->
       </ion-select>

     </ion-item>
      <button ion-button full (click)="toggleAppTheme1()">Change</button>
```

for the color.ts

```
    Color:string;
  Font:string;
  selectedTheme:String;
  selectedFont: String;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private settings:SettingsProvider ) 


  {
    this.settings.getActiveTheme().subscribe(val => this.selectedTheme = val);
    // this.settings.getActiveFont().subscribe(val => this.selectedFont = val);
    this.settings.getActiveFont().subscribe(val => this.selectedFont = val);
  }





      toggleAppTheme1()
      { 



        if (this.Color=='D'){ this.settings.setActiveTheme('Dark-theme');}

        else if(this.Color=='L'){ this.settings.setActiveTheme('Light-theme');}

        else if(this.Color=='M'){ this.settings.setActiveTheme('Medium-theme');} 

        else if(this.Color=='p'){ this.settings.setActiveTheme('Plain-theme');}
        else if(this.Color=='R'){ this.settings.setActiveTheme('Rich-theme');}
```